# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android

I created a new app with the name `MyBabyCanRead`
The package name is `com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.`

When I run the application I get his error in the logcat and I don't know why:

```
   10-21 15:42:12.108    1305-1322/com.example.claudio.mybabycanread E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL      EXCEPTION: Thread-165
      android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  act=com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.MENU }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
        at com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:26)
```

This is how my manifest looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.claudio.mybabycanread" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>
<application


    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >

    <activity

        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity

        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:name=".Level1"
        android:label="Level 1">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.LEVEL1" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity

        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:name=".Level1T"
        android:label="Level 1 Training">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.LEVEL1T" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:name=".TextToSpeechTest"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.TEXTTOSPEECHTEST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:name=".VideoPlayer"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.VIDEOPLAYER" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  </application>

 </manifest>
```

This is my splash.java file:

```
package com.example.claudio.mybabycanread;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
/**
* Created by Cl on 9/29/2014.
*/
public class Splash extends Activity {
MediaPlayer ourSong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle ClaudioFahmy) {
    super.onCreate(ClaudioFahmy);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent Level1 = new Intent("com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.MENU");
                startActivity(Level1);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I'm trying to be a clairvoyant, but in your Splash.java file under line 26: you have started activity for result in that line, and there you have a wrong String in the intent constructor: something like..

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.claudio.maxcanreadattheageof1");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Please upload your manifest file, the the error could also be there..

Comment: I changed line 26, but now I still get the same error, please see the error. I also posted my manifest. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Please upload your Splash.java file.. Do you know what intent filters are for? The error says, you fired an intent in your splash. java file, and you dont have an intent filter that handles that intent.

Comment: Ok. I uploaded the Splash.java file. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: ok, see that now that your error is different  -  now it doesnt show old package name, it shows a new one. "com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.MENU" - When you are starting this activity in your splash screen, what are you trying to achieve? open what? in your manifest you have to have an activity that has an intent filter to accept this intent you sent!

Comment: Yes, because I changed line 26 as you said. :-)

Comment: I was editing my answer. I pressed enter accidentally.

Comment: Now again i dont know what are you trying to achieve, but maybe you should change this line :             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />
with this line             <action android:name="com.example.claudio.mybabycanread.MENU" />

Comment: After the Splash activity, I want it to display the menu with all the other activities listed in it.

Comment: It seems to be working now. Thank you so much Loma Roma! How do I rate your answer 5 stars?

Comment: Im glad I could help. P.S. Read about intent filters and Intents in Android. ;)

Answer (score 1):

make sure your manifest file package is updated as `package=com.example.claudio.mybabycanread`

Comment: <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>